# .htpasswd asking for authentication on home page

Tags: htaccess

I have Wordpress installed on a subdomain. I added a .htpasswd file to the wp-admin folder.

This works as intended on the login page and if I try to cancel or close the pop-up window I get the server message,"This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested".

The problem is that it also asks for authentication on all the pages of my site but I don't get any server message when I cancel the authentication window.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the .htaccess file that instructs Apache to use the .htpasswd file? Is it also in wp-admin or is it above that directory in the wordpress root? It sounds like it's at the root and not in wp-admin.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware, the AJAX file `admin-ajax.php` is in the `wp-admin` directory too. So I guess your site is using AJAX to send requests in the background to the admin directory. Clicking it away lets the AJAX request fail, but the error isn’t displayed.

Change the .htaccess to:

```
AuthType     Basic
AuthName    'YOUR_AUTH_NAME'
AuthUserFile PATH_TO_HTPASSWORD
<Files '*'>
    Require valid-user
</Files>
<Files 'admin-ajax.php'>
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</Files>
```